is it possible to validate multiple resources?
I'm using the terraform-plugin-framework.
As a contrived example, say I have these resources:
resource "provider_resource" "thing" {

   do_build = true
}

resource "provider_resource_builder" "my_builder" {
     build = ["thing"]
}

Is it possible for my_builder to validate provider_resource.thing.do_build is true , before creating it ?

This is a frequent question to be honest, but in general one resource cannot access attributes of another resource with functionality intrinsic to the plugin. You can only rely on the user to supply exported attributes from one resource's schema as inputs to another resource's schema.

You could potentially use the SDK bindings to the API to Read whether the value is true, but this only provides information at the time of initial execution, and not during the execution as the resource could be modified, and so it is not foolproof.

@MatthewSchuchard fair criticism.  To be honest just looking for a sanity check, as I couldn't see a way from the documentation.  I'm very new to terraform plugins.
